# how to catch data!-nil error in url request

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I think I'm confused with do, catch and try. I use the following code to get information from my server, but when i turn of my wifi, the line after do{ throws a nil-error. I have another script where i check for reachability first, but I'm looking for a way to do it without that. "data!" must be what's throwing the error, because if there is no internet connection, i guess I can't get and data back. But I have no idea how to fix this. Ideally i would like to use the URLRequest to recognize that there is no wifi without using my reachability function. Im still pretty new to swift and have no idea how to fix this.

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "url")!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "club=BLA"
urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    do{
        // next line causes error in OFFLINE mode
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonResult)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: This is Swift 3 code. Why are you using any of those `NSxxx` classes? Don't use any of those classes. Don't use `NSURL`, use `URL`. Don't use `NSURLRequest`, use `URLRequest`. Don't use `NSDictionary`, use a Swift dictionary. Don't use `NSError`, use `Error`.

Comment: Ohhhh. thanx... converted this to swift 3 without even fully understanding swift 2 :) will look into updating this, thanx for pointing this out!

Comment: My general rule: never use force unwrapping unless you're 100% certain it will never be nil *AND* conditionally unwrapping would significantly complicate your code (even if you're certain it's safe, it's better to plan for unexpected failure unless the cost is high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything about your code needs to be fixed. Don't use `NSxxx` classes. Use the appropriate Swift class.

Don't force-unwrap optionals. Use `if let` to safely unwrap the values.

Here's your code rewritten with the correct types and valid handling of optionals to avoid your crash.

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
if let requestURL = URL(string: "url") {
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "club=BLA"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                    print(jsonResult)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly the way i needed, but had to fix 2 small warnings first. I had to move let postString up a line because it was used before it was declared. and then i had to move task.resume() up one line over the next bracket. THANK YOU

Comment: Oops - fixed those typos.

Answer (score 2):

The returned `data` object is `nil`, presumably because the network request failed or something (e.g. the URL) was incorrect. In your case it is because you are offline, and therefore no `data` can be returned.

You can check for this by [unwrapping the optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) with `guard let` (or `if let`) before using it:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    guard data = data else {
        // the returned data was nil, check error object
        return
    }

    do {
        // next line causes error in OFFLINE mode
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            print(jsonResult)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```